# Upgrade to High Sierra installed version of Fuse too old for OS

Tags: filesystem, high-sierra

I just updated to High Sierra, now I see this this message (as shown in the screen shot)

```
"Installed version of macOS unsupported.
The installed version of FUSE it too old for the operating system ..."
```

[image]

Could somebody help me -

a) Find out why / how and by whom fuse was installed (I have not done it specifically as far as I can recall)

b) How to upgrade it to remove the error

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you did not specifically install it, it likely came with something else you installed. you may have to go through your Applications folder and go to the website of each App and search for FUSE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are not aware of any app needing FUSE you can remove it. You should see an icon in System Preferences for FUSE. You can remove or update from there:

[image: FUSE System Preferences]

See also: [FUSE for macOS website](https://osxfuse.github.io)

Comment: Thanks Michael, I will try updating it (as cannot delete it as development machine and would need to find out what was using it), will tick the answer if it resolves the issue on reboot.

Comment: This still applies for MacOS Ventura (13.x). Search settings (or spotlight) for MacFUSE and this screen is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Going to the FUSE for macOS website, downloading and installing the latest version of FUSE from here solved he problem.  Less hassle than trying to find the App using the outdated version. Although when it installs it doesn't select the reverse compatability tool, its worth doing so.